# No permissions on dektrium user admin index action

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I installed dektrium user but when override the `AdminController.php` and tried to reach `admin/index` what I get is `Forbidden(403)`. After overriding the behaviors to:

```
'rules' => [
        [
           'allow' => true,
           'roles' => ['?'],
       ],
],
```

the error is still the same. Did this because I still don't have any roles. What can cause this behavior ? I am aiming at the origin `index.php` ( the one in the `dektrium\yii2-user` module). Thank you!

Comment: you want to create an action `index` which should be allowed for `guest` users without login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow these rules to override controllers for dektrium-user

**`directory structure`**

You can change the following if you want it into the frontend, only starting folder needs to be changed

```
- backend
   - controllers
     - user
       - AdminController
```

Your config for the `user` module under the `module` section should look like following

```
'modules' => [
  ..............
    'user' => [
            'controllerMap' => [
                'admin' => 'backend\controllers\user\AdminController' ,
            ] ,
```

For overriding the controller with a new action `index` your minimum code should look like below

**`AdminController`**

```
<?php 

namespace backend\controllers\user;
use dektrium\user\controllers\AdminController as BaseAdmin;

class AdminController extends BaseAdmin {

    public function behaviors() {
        $behaviours = parent::behaviors ();
        $behaviours['access']['rules'][] = [
            'allow' => true ,
            'actions' => [ 'index' ] ,
            'roles' => [ '?' ]
        ];
        return $behaviours;
    }

    public function actionIndex(){
        return $this->render('index');
    }
}
```

Comment: What I was missing was the `controllerMap` part. Now the problem is the same with the dektrium rbac module :D  Again `Forbidden(403)` and I think I followed the documentation exaclty if this is the whole thing - https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-rbac/blob/1.0.0-alpha/docs/installation.md

Comment: show your user section config under `module` section make sure you are not using `controllerMap` under the option `'as frontend' => 'dektrium\user\filters\FrontendFilter' ,` as this line will restrict access to admin controller from frontend application @TomaTomov

Comment: also verify your version by using `composer show -i` @TomaTomov

Comment: User version - 0.9.13. Rbac version - 1.0.0-alpha. My configuration in `backed/config/main.php` is `'user' => [
            // following line will restrict access to profile, recovery, registration and settings controllers from backend
            //'as backend' => 'dektrium\user\filters\BackendFilter',
            'controllerMap' => [
                'admin' => 'backend\controllers\user\AdminController'
            ],
        ],
        'rbac' => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\rbac\RbacWebModule',
        ],` in module section.

Comment: In `common\config\main.php` I've added user class like so `'modules' => [
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
            'enableGeneratingPassword' => true,
            'enableRegistration' => true,
        ],
    ],`

Comment: your config seems ok, have you updated your behavior as in the answer above?. @TomaTomov

Comment: Yes. I can access yii2-user `AdminController.php`. The problem now is the yii2-rbac controllers.

Comment: ahh ok i thought you had problem with the `AdminController` you can add a separate question with all the relative code related to configs in that question, will see what the problem is @TomaTomov